# Dynamic JavaScript drag and drop using array from localStorage

Tags: javascript, draggable

I seem to be having some trouble trying to teach myself the drag and drop events.  Before adding `thingy.draggable=true;`, the code only worked when highlighting then dragging.  I didn't like that. I used google to figure out what I needed to do to stop that -however, now it seems like that code broke the drag event.

### JavaScript

```
const appBuild = (eMD) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < eMD.kObj.length; i++) {
        /*this loop creates elements from an array in local storage*/
        
        var thingy = document.createElement("p"),
            ev;

        thingy.innerHTML = eMD.kObj[i];
        thingy.style.cursor = "grab";
        thingy.id = eMD.kObj[i];

        thingy.drag = event => drag(ev);
        thingy.drop = event => drop(ev);

        thingy.draggable = true;

        sideBar.append(thingy);
    }
};

const allowDrop = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

const drag = (ev) => {
    /* this function doesn't fire*/
    //console.log(ev);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

const drop = (ev) => {
    var newItem = document.createElement("p"),
        data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

    /* data is blank because dataTransfer.setData never happened */
    //console.log(data);

    newItem.innerHTML = data;
    ev.preventDefault();

    ev.target.appendChild(newItem);
}
```

### HTML

```
<body id="body">
  
  <div id="board" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

  <div id="sideBar"></div>

</body>
```

### eMD array in localStorage

```
kObj: ["a","b","c","d"];
```

Comment: You never assigned a handler for the drag event.

Comment: Is `, \`\` ev` intentional in `var thingy = document.createElement("p"),\`\` ev;` and if so, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @RandyCasburn They did. `thingy.drag = event => drag(ev);`

Comment: @FZs - thanks -didn't see - but in the arrow they pass `event` into the handler then call the `drag()` function with `ev` - not going to turn out well.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That may be the cause of the problem... I pointed that out too, but don't have time to investigate or write an answer.

Comment: @FZs that is an error here, i'm editing this post now.

Comment: Things you need to fix: 1. it is unclear why you want thingy to be a drop zone (`thingy.drop`) 2. assigning events in this fashion uses the _Global Event_ types of events - which means then need to be `ondrag` and `ondrop` 3. you pass `event` into your handler, yet use `ev` when making the calls to `drop(ev)` 4. `text` is not a _data type_ used in `.setText()` and `.getText()` - it should be a MIME type: `text/plain`. See if those changes help some.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks to both of you for catching my errors.  I greatly appreciate it.